# Using Pandas Lambda to compare two text strings from different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df:
name        givenname
 John           John
 Kim            Kimberly
```

I would like to create a new column with a 1 or 0 depeding on if its a match.

I have tried:

```
df['match'] = df.name.apply(lambda x: 1 if x == df.givenname else 0)
```

but I am getting

> **ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
> **
> I feel like this should be something simple but I cannot seem to get it working! Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the function on the columns `name` and `givenname` and in the lambda function `x` is each row of data, so you access the value of column `name` and compare it to the value in `givenname`.

```
df['match'] = df[['name','givenname']].apply(lambda x: 1 if x.name == x.givenname else 0, axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks. im getting a `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'name'` error. would that have someting to do with my dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

use this:-

```
df['match']=df.apply(lambda x: 1 if x['name'] == x['givenname'] else 0,axis=1)
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your desired output:-

```
    name    givenname   match
0   John    John        1
1   Kim     Kimberly    0
```

Comment: thanks! this works too, i just saw the other one first!

Comment: Are you sure that other one is giving you correct output?