# Pandas groupby and lambda functions to compare strings across columns

Tags: pandas, lambda

I have the following dataframe:

```
  A         B           C           D            E           F
1001    J. Smith    J. Smith    P. Jones    S. Jackson  P. Peterson
1001    J. Smith    J. Smith    P. Jones    S. Jackson  P. Peterson
1001    S. Jackson  J. Smith    P. Jones    S. Jackson  P. Peterson
1001    P. Jones    J. Smith    P. Jones    S. Jackson  P. Peterson
1002    S. Jackson  S. Jackson  J. Smith    P. Peterson P. Jones
1002    J. Smith    S. Jackson  J. Smith    P. Peterson P. Jones
1002    S. Jackson  S. Jackson  J. Smith    P. Peterson P. Jones
1002    J. Smith    S. Jackson  J. Smith    P. Peterson P. Jones
```

I am trying to generate the below dataframe based upon the following criteria:

1. Groupby column A;
2. If the entry in column C exists within the column B (post-groupby of column A), return 1 in new column G, otherwise return 0;
3. The process at step 2 is then repeated for columns C vs D, C vs E etc.

.

```
 A          B           C           D             E           F     G   H   I   J
1001    J. Smith    J. Smith    P. Jones    S. Jackson  P. Peterson 1   1   1   0
1001    J. Smith    J. Smith    P. Jones    S. Jackson  P. Peterson 1   1   1   0
1001    S. Jackson  J. Smith    P. Jones    S. Jackson  P. Peterson 1   1   1   0
1001    P. Jones    J. Smith    P. Jones    S. Jackson  P. Peterson 1   1   1   0
1002    S. Jackson  S. Jackson  J. Smith    P. Peterson P. Jones    1   0   1   1
1002    P. Jones    S. Jackson  J. Smith    P. Peterson P. Jones    1   0   1   1
1002    S. Jackson  S. Jackson  J. Smith    P. Peterson P. Jones    1   0   1   1
1002    P. Peterson S. Jackson  J. Smith    P. Peterson P. Jones    1   0   1   1
```

I have researched and attempted to use lambda functions, np.where and combinations of boolean indexing from this forum but have been unsuccessful. For example, a lot of the lambda function questions seem to relate to [comparing string versus string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66722004/using-pandas-lambda-to-compare-two-text-strings-from-different-columns).

I am trying to compare a string in one cell, versus an entire column of values. My attempt seems logical but I'm not sure how to rectify this to achieve the above.

```
df['G'] = df.groupby(['A']).apply(lambda x: 1 if x['B'] == x['C'] else 0)
```

I have also tried some less traditional approaches such as the below. Here, column Z is a column of 1s: if B and C do not match, replace the value in column z with a 0. Still, this does not achieve the desired outcome as above.

```
df['Y'] = (
    df['Z'].where(df['B'] == df['C'],other=0)
    .groupby([df['A']])
    .transform('count') 
)

df['G'] = df['Y'] / df['Y']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each group, you could use numpy broadcasting to return a matrix where each column is one of `C`, `D`, `E` and `F`, and where each value is True if it's in `B`, False otherwise. Then just use `any(axis=1)` to convert the matrix into a list of booleans where each value is True if at least one value in the column it represents was True, False otherwise:

```
values = dfe['A'].map(dfe.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: (x['B'].to_numpy()[:, None] == x.drop(['A', 'B'], axis=1).to_numpy()).any(axis=0).astype(int)))
df[['G', 'H', 'I', 'J']] = pd.DataFrame(values.tolist())
```

Output:

```
>>> df
      A           B           C         D            E            F  G  H  I  J
0  1001    J. Smith    J. Smith  P. Jones   S. Jackson  P. Peterson  1  1  1  0
1  1001    J. Smith    J. Smith  P. Jones   S. Jackson  P. Peterson  1  1  1  0
2  1001  S. Jackson    J. Smith  P. Jones   S. Jackson  P. Peterson  1  1  1  0
3  1001    P. Jones    J. Smith  P. Jones   S. Jackson  P. Peterson  1  1  1  0
4  1002  S. Jackson  S. Jackson  J. Smith  P. Peterson     P. Jones  1  1  0  0
5  1002    J. Smith  S. Jackson  J. Smith  P. Peterson     P. Jones  1  1  0  0
6  1002  S. Jackson  S. Jackson  J. Smith  P. Peterson     P. Jones  1  1  0  0
7  1002    J. Smith  S. Jackson  J. Smith  P. Peterson     P. Jones  1  1  0  0
```